# Nifi GetEventHub is multiplying the data by the number of nodes

Tags: azure, hortonworks-data-platform, apache-nifi, azure-eventhub

I have some flows that get the data from an azure eventhub, im using the GetAzureEventhub processor. The data that im getting is being multiplyed by the number of nodes that I have in the cluster, I have 4 nodes. If I indicate to the processor to just run on the primary node, the data is not replicated 4 times.

I found that the eventhub for each consumer group accepts up to 5 readers, I read this in [this article](http://winterttr.me/2015/09/05/Concurrent-Reader-on-a-specific-EventHub-Partition-within-one-consumer-group/), each reader will have its own separate offset and they consume the same data. So in conclussion Im reading the same data 4 times.

I have 2 questions:
How can I coordinate this 4 nodes in order to go throught the same reader?
In case this is not posible, how can indicate nifi to just one of the nodes to read?

Thanks, if you need any clarification, ask for it.

Answer (score 3):

GetAzureEventHub currently does not perform any coordination across nodes so you would have to run it on primary node only to avoid duplication.

The processor would require refactoring to perform coordination across the nodes of the cluster and assign unique partitions to each node, and handle failures (i.e. if a node consuming partition 1 goes down, another node has to take over partition 1).

If the Azure client provided this coordination somehow (similar to the Kafka client) then it would require less work on the NiFi side, but I'm not familiar enough with Azure to know if it provides anything like this.

Comment: Thanks a lot Bryan! I will try If I can do it myself.